# Deleting rows from DatagridView and Database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to delete the selected rows from datagrid view and database.. My code is deleting from the datagridview but not from the actual database, is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
private void btnDelRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView2.Rows[i];
                if (dr.Selected == true)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);

                        Query = "Delete from TblEmployer where Id=" + i + "";
                        theReader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
                        conn.CloseConnection();
                        MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
                    }


                }
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the row indexes of the control match the `Id` column?

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, post an answer of what you did to fix it, so other people can learn from your experience.